# Array to block list

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
0 = Array('attr' => Array('class' => 'class1'), 'content'=>'class-1-content'),
1 = Array('attr' => Array(), 'content'=>'...'),
2 = Array('attr' => Array('class' => 'whatever'), 'content'=>'...'),
3 = Array('attr' => Array('class' => 'anything'), 'content'=>'...'),
4 = Array('attr' => Array(), 'content'=>'...'),
5 = Array('attr' => Array('class' => 'class2'), 'content'=>'...'),
6 = Array('attr' => Array('key' => 'more-here'), 'content'=>'...'),
7 = Array('attr' => Array('class' => 'class1'), 'content'=>'class-1-again'),
8 = Array('attr' => Array('another-attr' => ''), 'content'=>'...'),
9 = Array('attr' => Array(), 'content'=>'...'),
10 = Array('attr' => Array('class' => 'and-so-on'), 'content'=>'...'),
...
```

I'd like to create a functionality picking up specific attributes (like in my case above all classes equal to 'class1' or 'class2') and group these until anything else "kicks in". Basically to create an outcome like this:

```
0 = Array(type='class1', 'content='class-1-content', block=Array(
    0 = Array('attr' => Array(), 'content'=>'...'),
    1 = Array('attr' => Array('class' => 'whatever'), 'content'=>'...'),
    2 = Array('attr' => Array('class' => 'anything'), 'content'=>'...'),
    3 = Array('attr' => Array(), 'content'=>'...')
),
1 = Array(type='class2', 'content'=>'content-class-2', block=Array( 
    0 = Array('attr' => Array('key' => 'more-here'), 'content'=>'...'),
),
2 = Array(type='class1', 'content'=>'class-1-again', block=Array( 
    0 = Array('attr' => Array('another-attr' => ''), 'content'=>'...'),
    1 = Array('attr' => Array(), 'content'=>'...'),
    2 = Array('attr' => Array('class' => 'and-so-on'), 'content'=>'...')
)
```

Could anyone please help me out figuring out how to do this in the best way? Would be great to be able to create a "kick-in-list" like Array('class1', 'class2', 'class3') etc in order to create these blocks.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `convert` function that assembles the array as you indicated. It takes the original array as first argument and a regular expression to match your classes with as second argument:

```
function convert($data, $pattern) {
    $result = array();
    foreach($data as $element) {
        if (array_key_exists("attr", $element) && 
                array_key_exists("class", $element["attr"]) && 
                preg_match($pattern, $element["attr"]["class"]) ) {
            $group = $element;
            // set the "type" key/value
            $group["type"] = $group["attr"]["class"];
            // remove the "class" key
            unset($group["attr"]["class"]);
            // remove the "attr" key, unless not empty
            if (sizeof($group["attr"]) == 0) {
                unset($group["attr"]);
            }
            // initialise "block" for collecting the next items
            $group["block"] = array();
            // add the group array to the result
            $result[] = $group;
        } else {
            if (!sizeof($result)) {
                // create a "pre" group if there was not yet a group:
                $result[] = array("type" => "pre", "content" => null, "block" => array());
            }
            // add to block
            $result[sizeof($result)-1]["block"][] = $element; 
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

// Set-up test data
$data = Array(
    Array('attr' => Array('class' => 'class1'), 'content'=>'class-1-content'),
    Array('attr' => Array(), 'content'=>'...'),
    Array('attr' => Array('class' => 'whatever'), 'content'=>'...'),
    Array('attr' => Array('class' => 'anything'), 'content'=>'...'),
    Array('attr' => Array(), 'content'=>'...'),
    Array('attr' => Array('class' => 'class2'), 'content'=>'class-2-content'),
    Array('attr' => Array('key' => 'more-here'), 'content'=>'...'),
    Array('attr' => Array('class' => 'class1'), 'content'=>'class-1-again'),
    Array('attr' => Array('another-attr' => ''), 'content'=>'...'),
    Array('attr' => Array(), 'content'=>'...'),
    Array('attr' => Array('class' => 'and-so-on'), 'content'=>'...')
);

// Call function on test data, grouping on class1 and class2
var_export (convert($data, "/^class[1-2]$/"));
```

The output of the above script is:

```
array (
    0 => array ('content' => 'class-1-content', 'type' => 'class1', 'block' => array (
        0 => array ('attr' => array (), 'content' => '...'),
        1 => array ('attr' => array ('class' => 'whatever'), 'content' => '...'),
        2 => array ('attr' => array ('class' => 'anything'), 'content' => '...'),
        3 => array ('attr' => array (), 'content' => '...'),
        ),
    ),
    1 => array ('content' => 'class-2-content', 'type' => 'class2', 'block' => array (
        0 => array ('attr' => array ('key' => 'more-here'), 'content' => '...'),
        ),
    ),
    2 => array ('content' => 'class-1-again', 'type' => 'class1', 'block' => array (
        0 => array ('attr' => array ('another-attr' => ''), 'content' => '...'),
        1 => array ('attr' => array (), 'content' => '...'),
        2 => array ('attr' => array ('class' => 'and-so-on'), 'content' => '...'),
    ),
  ),
)
```

...which is what you specified as expected output.

There is some sanity check to avoid the removal of the `attr` key when it would have more than only the group's `class` attribute. This does not occur in your test data, but better be safe.

Also, if the data does not start with an element to group by (i.e. not a `class1` or `class2` case in the example), a dummy "pre" group is put in the result that will group those orphan arrays. An example of that:

```
$data = Array(
    Array('attr' => Array(), 'content'=>'...'),
    Array('attr' => Array('class' => 'whatever'), 'content'=>'...'), 
    Array('attr' => Array('class' => 'anything'), 'content'=>'...'), 
    Array('attr' => Array(), 'content'=>'...'),
    Array('attr' => Array('class' => 'class1'), 'content'=>'class-1-content'),
    Array('attr' => Array(), 'content'=>'...')
);
```

Will result in this output:

```
array (
    0 => array ('type' => 'pre', 'content' => NULL, 'block' => array (
        0 => array ('attr' => array (), 'content' => '...'),
        1 => array ('attr' => array ('class' => 'whatever'), 'content' => '...'),
        2 => array ('attr' => array ('class' => 'anything'), 'content' => '...'),
        3 => array ('attr' => array (), 'content' => '...')
        ),
    ),
    1 => array ('content' => 'class-1-content', 'type' => 'class1', 'block' => array (
        0 => array ('attr' => array (), 'content' => '...'),
        ),
    ),
)
```

Comment: Whoa - thanks! Works great. Just like you indicated, great with the attr key to be preserved. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry to bother you once more. I realized that there are cases where there's none of the "listen-to"-classes in the beginning of the array. Instead the array starts with stuff like this:

    Array('attr' => Array(), 'content'=>'...'),
    Array('attr' => Array('class' => 'whatever'), 'content'=>'...'),
    Array('attr' => Array('class' => 'anything'), 'content'=>'...'),
    Array('attr' => Array(), 'content'=>'...'),

Could you help me out to get that into a block as well, marking the type-attribute as "pre" and with null as the content's value?

Comment: Code updated to support that. Change is in the `else` part of the function.

Comment: Man, I'm speachless regarding your help. Thanks _so_ much, works flawless!

Comment: I was a bit too fast though, there seems to be an error somehow - blocks are now nested into each other. Do you happen to have an example to show me that I'm wrong here?

Comment: I added in my answer an example based on the stuff you provided above in comments. The output seems correct to me. I don't see how blocks could get nested. There are three places in the code where `block` is referenced, and in all cases it is a key that occurs in an array that in turn is an element in the `result` array. And there is only one statement where `block` is populated. And it is clear that *only* original elements are appended to it, so nesting is excluded. Are you sure you use the same code, and that you provide well-structured data to the function?

Comment: You're perfectly right - there seems to be some issues with the data I provide to the function, sorry for bothering you - should've checked better. Thing is, it's quite a bumpy ride until I get that data in such a shape that I can pass it on to your well-working function - it's about parsing an html-file with different classes, basically no semantics.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished using a [`foreach()`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) over your current array. Then if there is a `['attr']['class']` value set, we check it if starts with `class` using [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php). If `strpos() === 0` we add it as a new top array element, if not we add it as a new sub array element to the last top array element using a simple counter var, ie. `$i`.

```
$arrays = Array(
  Array('attr' => Array('class' => 'class1'), 'content'=>'class-1-content'),
  Array('attr' => Array(), 'content'=>'...'),
  Array('attr' => Array('class' => 'whatever'), 'content'=>'...'),
  Array('attr' => Array('class' => 'anything'), 'content'=>'...'),
  Array('attr' => Array(), 'content'=>'...'),
  Array('attr' => Array('class' => 'class2'), 'content'=>'...'),
  Array('attr' => Array('key' => 'more-here'), 'content'=>'...'),
  Array('attr' => Array('class' => 'class1'), 'content'=>'class-1-again'),
  Array('attr' => Array('another-attr' => ''), 'content'=>'...'),
  Array('attr' => Array(), 'content'=>'...'),
  Array('attr' => Array('class' => 'and-so-on'), 'content'=>'...')
  );

$i=-1; // simple counter
$newArray=array();
foreach($arrays as $array){
  if (isset($array['attr']['class']) && (0 === strpos($array['attr']['class'], 'class'))) {
      $i++; // increase the counter
      $newArray[]=$array; // add a new array element
    }
  else {
      $newArray[$i]['block'][]=$array; // add a new sub array element
    }
}
```

example here - https://3v4l.org/U1V8n